# ImportError: No module named 'bpy'

Tags: python, blender, bpy

I am getting Error `ImportError: No module named 'bpy'` in Blender console. I am importing `bpy` module inside Blender console but still getting the Error. After long Googling I found that no one is getting the same error inside Blender.

Using Blender 2.7 and python 3.4.

My code:

```
import sys   
import bpy     
sys.path.append("C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages")    
import serial    
import GameLogic    
contr = GameLogic.getCurrentController()    
own = contr.owner    
dane=open('dane.txt', 'rb')    
x=dane.read()    
dane.close()    
y = int(x)    
print ("y=", y)    

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=(y), axis=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1.0, snap=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', snap_point=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), snap_align=False, snap_normal=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), release_confirm=False)
```

Output at Blender console:

```
ImportError: No module named 'bpy'  
Python script error - object 'Cube', controller 'Python':  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "qqq.py", line 2, in <module>  
ImportError: No module named 'bpy'
```

Comment: there is an answer over at the blender stackexchange community: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/getting-started-no-module-called-bpy-outside-of-blender

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem in collab but on my PC it was worked well:

[image]

type this in your anaconda prompt:

```
pip install bpy
```

Source: https://pypi.org/project/bpy/)